# Designing a hierarchical tree for a higher dimension data

Tags: tree, hierarchy, dimensions

Given a 1 dimension set of random numbers, we simply go through the set, and push the data down the tree. In one dimension, this is very simple. We can simply compare the value of the data, and decide where the data will propagate down the tree.

However, for higher dimension, distance starts to become blurry, and it is more difficult to decide which data should go where down the tree.

In fact, if we are to design a hierarchical tree that contains a set of high dimension vectors, (for instance, 128 dimension SIFT features) how can we decide which of each n dimension vector should go to which subtree and so on? What are some of the things we do?

Comment: What is a hierarchical tree, as opposed to a tree?

Comment: The same actually. I just wanna emphasize the hierarchical part.

Comment: I re-tagged this, because this question isn't specific to SIFT, and the data isn't hierarchical, only the tree is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Random trees

A [random tree](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/users/breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm) is a common technique for classification or clustering.

Here's how you decide on how to split each node of the tree:

- Select a random k (something small, like 5) out of the 128 SIFT dimensions.
- Determine which of those k dimensions provides the best split of the data.

So, each node will need to store:

1. The dimension to use
2. The decision threshold to apply to that dimension

Leaves will store:

- A class prediction, or some statistic about the data points that ended up at that leaf node.